# Custom Wordpress Plugin Not Saving Settings

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm working on my first custom WP plugin and I'm trying to register a setting using the Settings API. I've followed a number of guides, and I've successfully created an admin menu page with the section and field defined in the plugin, but the single setting (in the code its `fbm_lockout_updates`) will not save, and no table in the database has been created for it.

EDIT: It *is* in fact in the options table. I was mistaken about that much. However, my options page still cant seem to update it, so I suppose my callback function is bad?

After trying a dozen things, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Here is the relevant code edited for brevity:

```
/* Create Menu */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'fbm_config_menu' );
function fbm_config_menu() {    
    $page_title = 'Sample Plugin';   
    $menu_title = 'Sample Plugin Config';   
    $capability = 'manage_options';   
    $menu_slug  = 'fbm_config';   
    $function   = 'fbm_config_page';
add_menu_page( 
        $page_title,                  
        $menu_title,                   
        $capability,                   
        $menu_slug,                   
        $function
    ); 
}

/* Register Settings and Fields */

function fbm_register_settings() {
        
    register_setting( 'fbm_config', 'fbm_lockout_updates');
        
    add_settings_section(
        'fbm_restriction_section',
        'Development Restrictions',
        'fbm_restriction_callback',
        'fbm_config'
    );
        
    add_settings_field(
        'fbm_lockout_updates_field',
        'Lockout Updates',
        'fbm_lockout_field_callback',
        'fbm_config',
        'fbm_restriction_section'
    );
        
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'fbm_register_settings' );


/* Settings Callbacks */

function fbm_restriction_callback() {
    ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Description of Setting Section', 'fbm_config' ); ?></p>
    <?php
}

function fbm_lockout_field_callback() {
    $setting = get_option('fbm_lockout_updates');
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fbm_lockout_updates" value="0" <?php checked('1', $setting); ?> >
    <?php
}

/* Load Admin Page */

function fbm_config_page(){ 
        
        if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) {
            add_settings_error( 'fbm_con_messages', 'fbm_con_message', __( 'Settings Saved', 'fbm_config' ), 'updated' );
        }
        settings_errors( 'fbm_con_messages' );
        ?>

        <div class="wrap">
            <h1><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php 
                    settings_fields( 'fbm_config' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'fbm_config' );
                    submit_button( 'Save Settings' );
                ?>
            </form>
        <div>
<?php }  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case register_setting will save your data in wp-options table, take a look into it.

Recommended if you want your setting to be shown in the wordpress api use both admin and api hook

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'bm_register_settings' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'fbm_register_settings' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I was eventually able to find it, I must have not been looking hard enough. I still have the original problem named in the title - the data is not updating from my options page. I suppose the problem then is the callback function?